# Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined - Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I installed latest Angular CLI and was trying to create a new app i am getting the below  error. I uninstalled , cleaned cache , cleaned by forcing it , installed , updated npm...restarted computer :-) 
My versions Angular CLI: 6.1.2 Node: 8.11.3
[image]

Comment: Can you post your node version and angular cli as well : node -v , ng -v

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.1.2 Node: 8.11.3 
Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the other suggestions here, but ended up removing and re-installing Node.js and NPM.

Finally did the trick for me.

Comment: I have marked your answer as answer as i did this step as well....It just went off my head thanks

Comment: Great! I will Edit my comment, so it makes sense to the next person - thank you @ShivprasadKoirala

Answer (score 9):

In our case was old package: @angular/pwa
Once we update it from: 0.6.8 to 0.7.5 everything started working fine.

Comment: Updated @angular/pwa@ to latest (0.8.0-rc.1) worked for me

Comment: Updated @angular/pwa@latest (^0.10.4) is worked for me too

Answer (score 3):

I reinstalled NodeJS.
I deleted `node_modules` folder from user directory and hit `npm install` and it started working

Comment: unbelievable! before getting this error did you update cli and typescript?

Comment: Did not update TS , installed CLI twice one older version and then latest. Looks like the multiple install can be issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Shivprasad Koirala,

I had the same problem as you but the solution did not do it for me. Frankly speaking, it is a little bit odd that re-installing node.js fixes your problem because it should not conflict with Angular/CLI but in any case, good for you.

For my case, the solution was a bit different. I had accidentally once tried to create a new project in my username's folder. This was wrong, and I had canceled the procedure but
it seems like that it had created one or two things. So in that case the steps are:

1. Navigate to your **username folder** by opening windows explorer and typing in the address bar `%HomePath%`
2. Check if the file `package.json` and if the folder `node_module` exist. If so, you can **delete** them safely.

*If you have a Linux, again you need to navigate to your home directory and delete both those entries.*

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. delete `package-lock.json`
4. Edit `package.json` devDependencies with these package versions:

   - `"@angular/cli": "6.0.8"`,
   - `"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.4"`,
   - `"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.6.8"`,
   - `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8"`,
   - `"@ngrx/schematics": "6.0.1"`,
   - `"@nrwl/schematics": "6.0.4"`, (if using nrwl/nx)
   - `"ng-packagr": "^3.0.0-rc.2"`,
   - `"typescript": "2.9.2"`
5. `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

Updating all my angular schematic packages worked for me.

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 8.11.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.3
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.3
@angular/cli                      6.2.3
@angular/pwa                      0.7.5
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.8.3
@schematics/update                0.8.3
rxjs                              5.5.12
typescript                        2.4.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the most repeated solution: reinstalling nodejs and angular cli, deleting node_modules and running  `npm i`, but it did not work.

Finally, I tried upgrading angular schematics and it worked for me:

```
npm i -g @schematics/angular@7 

npm i @schematics/angular@7
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, install `node.js` from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and follow the steps below.

**To install the Angular CLI:**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

To create project

```
ng new my-project //my-project is the name of the project
```

Change directory to project folder

```
cd my-project
```

To run the Angular project

```
ng serve
```

Comment: Done all these already....As said i am getting a error when i do ng new app

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading `@angular/cli` to version `6.1.5`. Downgrading it to `6.0.8` solved problem.

My problem had been occurring during `ng g lib ...`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after updating the project from v6 to v7. However, I missed updating `@schematics/angular` to a newer version. Apparently, there was some compatibility mismatch that wasn't noted in the `package.json`s that caused this issue.

The best way I've found to figure out what the versions of stuff should be is to create a new project with the version of Angular you are trying to use. Once created, look at it's `package.json` to figure what versions should be compatible with what.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick, it will work :

> Navigate to Parent Folders i.e.C Drive, Users, admin, download respectively and check if any angular files exist [ package.json, node_modules, etc.] and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case @schematics/angular was completely missing from my package.json -- not sure what happened.

Running

```
npm i @schematics/angular --save-dev
```

Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I tried explicitly installing `@schematics/angular` and setting my default cli collection using:

```
npm i @schematics/angular --save-dev
ng config cli.defaultCollection @schematics/angular
```

It did not work for me.

So instead, since I'm already using ngrx in my project, I opted for `@ngrx/schematics` as my default.

```
npm i @ngrx/schematics -D
ng config cli.defaultCollection @ngrx/schematics
```

That worked for me.